# Unhandled exception of type System.FormatException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

When I start the program, Visual Studio 2015 (I use WPF and C#) always gives me an unhandled exception of the type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

```
string ascii = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < dec.Length; i += 3)
{
    ascii += Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(dec.Substring(i, 3))); // The exception occurs here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are non-numeric characters in your string. That is what is causing your `FormatException`.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).